# Getter function to return a nested struct that contains mapping?

Tags: solidity, struct

For example,

```
    struct SomeStruct {
        uint _someUint;
        uint _someUint2;
        mapping(address => uint) _someMapping;
    }
```

A getter function for a non-nested struct could be

```
    function retSomeStruct() public returns(SomeStruct memory) {
        
    }
```

But this doesn't work for the nested one,

```
TypeError: Types containing (nested) mappings can only be parameters or return variables of internal or library functions.
```

To return a struct containing _someUint and _someUint2, apart from destructing, is there other ways to just skip the mapping?

Comment: https://codeforgeek.com/mappings-inside-structs-in-solidity/ this instructions might help you

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a mapping for your SomeStruct, you could implement this smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract Test {

     struct SomeStruct {
        uint someUint;
        uint someUint2;
        mapping(address => uint) someMapping;
    }
    
    mapping(address=>SomeStruct) mapStruct;

    function addElement(uint _someUint, uint _someUint2, address _address, uint _valueAddress) public {
        mapStruct[_address].someUint = _someUint;
        mapStruct[_address].someUint2 = _someUint2;
        mapStruct[_address].someMapping[_address] = _valueAddress;
    }

    function getElement(address _address) external view returns(uint _someUint, uint _someUint2) {
        return (mapStruct[_address].someUint, mapStruct[_address].someUint2);
    }
}
```

NOTE: In `getElement()` function I returned all struct attributes without nested mapping.